# How to get ime language info?( windows, C++ )

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ime

I need to get the currently selected IME language setting in Windows.

I have found ImmGetConversionStatus(), but it doesn't return the currently selected language.

Answer (score 2):

Though this question was asked a long time ago.. I believe you might have solved it by yourself. :)

Did you try? :
If on Windows 7: GetUserDefaultLocaleName Function
Syntax:

```
int GetUserDefaultLocaleName(
  __out  LPWSTR lpLocaleName,
  __in   int cchLocaleName
);
```

lpLocaleName holds the current culture.

Check docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318136%28VS.85%29.aspx

Just FYI,
check these too:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318135%28VS.85%29.aspx
and also 'support.microsoft.com/kb/193080'

Comment: thanks, but I want to know current keyboad local(language) info. not default language. I had ImmGetConversionStatus() function. Sorry, my poor english ability.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12954320/964053

...you must do sth like this:

```
HWND fore = GetForegroundWindow(); // Every window has it's own current language (keyboard layout)
DWORD tpid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(fore, 0);
HKL hKL = GetKeyboardLayout(tpid);
WORD wd;
ToAsciiEx(VirtualKey, ScanCode, KeyState, (LPWORD)&wd, 0, hKL);
```