# How to determine the current input language?

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard, keyboard-hook

I am designing an on screen keyboard,

I need to determine which language been set by the user and which language he is using now in the other threads,

i.e. I need to know the language selected in the taskbar language switcher:

[image: language switcher]

P.S. current culture returns the language used in the on screen keyboard application, which is not the case I am looking for..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was to get the Keyboard Layout for the foreground window, and then apply it to the on screen keyboard, and check for the language in the usual ways..

```
            IntPtr fore = GetForegroundWindow();
            uint tpid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(fore, IntPtr.Zero);
            IntPtr hKL = GetKeyboardLayout(tpid);
            hKL = (IntPtr)(hKL.ToInt32() & 0x0000FFFF);
            InputLanguageManager m = InputLanguageManager.Current;
            m.CurrentInputLanguage = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(hKL.ToInt32());
            //IntPtr i = LoadKeyboardLayout(hKL.ToString(), 1);

            InputLanguage = InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage.ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

you can also get using [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WMISample
{
    public class MyWMIQuery
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS"); 

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_BIOS instance");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("CurrentLanguage: {0}", queryObj["CurrentLanguage"]);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```