# An easy way to get readable text out of keyboard hooks in c#?

Tags: c#

My [C# keylogger](http://code.google.com/p/klog-sharp/source/browse/trunk/Keylogger/UserActivityHook.cs?r=2) stores keyboard hooks in this format :

Example :

```
Hello World 123
```

Is stored like this :

```
HLSHIFTKeySpaceWLSHIFTKeyORLDNumPad1NumPad2NumPad3
```

Currently, I'm solving this problem using the function below after retrieving the data from database :

```
  function parse_data($data) {

   $data = str_replace('NumPad0','0',$data);
   $data= str_replace('NumPad1','1',$data);
   $data = str_replace('NumPad2','2',$data);
   $data = str_replace('NumPad3','3',$data);
   $data = str_replace('NumPad4','4',$data);
   $data = str_replace('NumPad5','5',$data);
   $data = str_replace('NumPad6','6',$data);
   $data = str_replace('NumPad7','7',$data);
   $data = str_replace('NumPad8','8',$data);
   $data = str_replace('NumPad9','9',$data);
   $data = str_replace('Decimal','.',$data);

   // replace + / * - 
   $data = str_replace('Multiply','*',$data);
   $data = str_replace('Subtract','-',$data);
   $data = str_replace('Add','+',$data);
   $data = str_replace('Divide','/',$data);

   .... after 100 or 150 other lines to replace all possible occurances
   return $data;

 }
```

However, I'm pretty sure this approach is totally wrong, and inaccurate, because I can only see what is being pressed on user's keyboard but I cannot see what is being written (written charachters depends on selected keyboard language)

**What do I want to do ?**

I want to make all these replacement within my c# code before inserting the information into database

**My question is :**

Is there any built-in function in C# to handle this work ? Otherwise. What is the easiest way to handle all this work in C# before inserting hooks into database ?

[Click here to see my C# code and how I am getting the hooks](http://code.google.com/p/klog-sharp/source/browse/trunk/Keylogger/UserActivityHook.cs?r=2)

Comment: Keylogger? Are you the next big 'hacker'?

Comment: I'm using this for my business to control my customers online, not for what you actually think

Comment: Get the input language, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951067/how-to-determine-the-current-input-language and you could probably take it from there.